# ASM: getting local variable name and value inside a method of a class

Tags: java, instrumentation, java-bytecode-asm

I want to extract local variable name and values present inside a method of a class using ASM. Kindly provide a suggestion.

Comment: What do you consider a field inside a method?

Comment: I mean the local variable name and value. I edited the question.

Answer (score 1):

In Java Bytecode, local variables are lumped into a locals list, which will contain at the beginning of the method parameters (including the receiver - the reference to `this`). Then, when local variables are declared, they are allocated next. Finally, if a local variable or parameter is not going to be used again, the space is "freed" so it can be used again for another variable.

The relation between local variable names and their position on the locals list can be obtained from a [`MethodVisitor#visitLocalVariable(...)`](https://asm.ow2.io/javadoc/org/objectweb/asm/MethodVisitor.html#visitLocalVariable-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-org.objectweb.asm.Label-org.objectweb.asm.Label-int-) or from a [`LocalVariableNode`](https://asm.ow2.io/javadoc/org/objectweb/asm/tree/LocalVariableNode.html) (only if the class was compiled with debugging information).

The local variable values cannot be obtained just by looking at the bytecode with ASM, you must either add instructions to print the local variable's value at the point(s) you want. An option would be to detect store instructions and insert instructions to log the value before them.

Example (assumes that all variables are `int`, would need to call an overloaded version of `log` for other types).

```
// In a AdviceAdapter
private static final Type VAR_LOGGER = Type.getInternalName(VarLogger.class);
private static final Method LOG_I = Method.getMethod("void log(int, int)");
private static final Method LOG_L = Method.getMethod("void log(long, int)");
private static final Method LOG_F = Method.getMethod("void log(float, int)");
private static final Method LOG_D = Method.getMethod("void log(double, int)");
private static final Method LOG_A = Method.getMethod("void log(Object, int)");

@Override
public void visitVarInsn(int opcode, int var) {
    if (isStoreOp(opcode)) {
        dup();
        push(var);
        invokeStatic(VAR_LOGGER, getLogMethod(opcode));
    }
    super.visitVarInsn(opcode, var);
}

private boolean isStoreOp(int opcode) {
    switch (opcode) {
        case ISTORE:
        case LSTORE:
        case FSTORE:
        case DSTORE:
        case ASTORE:
            return true;
        default:
            return false;
    }
}

private Method getLogMethod(int opcode) {
    switch (opcode) {
        case ISTORE: return LOG_I;
        case LSTORE: return LOG_L;
        case FSTORE: return LOG_F;
        case DSTORE: return LOG_D;
        case ASTORE: return LOG_A;
        default:
            throw new RuntimeException("Invalid store code: " + opcode);
    }
}

@Override
public void visitMaxs(int maxStack, int maxLocals) {
    super.visitMaxs(maxStack + 3, maxLocals);
}
```

Note: the override of `visitMaxs` is necessary only if you are not using `COMPUTE_MAXS`.